# Call service for each element found from another service and then populate an array with results

Tags: arrays, angular, service

**Problem:** 
Trying to populate a html table with two services. First I'm calling a service to retrieve all products. Then for each element I'm calling another service that accepts the `fabricplanid` as a parameter and returns the object if exists. If exists I push it to an array, but if returns an error 404 I push a string to the same array. 
The problem I'm facing is that the values inside the array, don't match the corresponding `fabricPlanId` of the product.

This is the product.component.ts file that when called execute this service and populates a table using a ngfor.

```
products:Product[];

  //view
  fabricplan: Fabricplan[];
  plan_desc: Array<String> = [];

  //view select
  fabricplans: Fabricplan[];



ngOnInit() {

this.productservice.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
    this.products = products;
    console.log("Produtos", this.products);

    this.products.forEach( element => {
      console.log(element.fabricPlanId);
      this.fabricplanservice.getfabricplan(element.fabricPlanId).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.fabricplan = response;
          this.plan_desc.push(this.fabricplan['description']);
        },
        (error) => {
          if(error.status === 404){
            this.plan_desc.push('No fabric plan');
          }
        });
      });
  });

 console.log("Planos de fabrico", this.plan_desc);
}
```

**The product.component.html file**

```
 <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Number</th>
            <th scope="col">Fabric Plan</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Price €</th>
            <th scope="col">Ative</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr scope="row" id="table" *ngFor="let product of products let i = index"(click)="open(content, product.id)">
           <td>{{ i+1 }}</td>
           <td>{{ plan_desc[i] }}</td>
           <td>{{ product?.name }}</td>
           <td>{{ product?.description }}</td>
           <td>{{ product?.price }}</td>
           <td>{{ product?.active }}</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

**Response body**

**Products**

```
{
active: true,
description: " descrição do prod 1",
fabricPlanId: 1,
id: 1,
name: "Produto 1",
price: 1
}
```

**FabricPlans**

```
{
dateStart: "2019-10-30T00:00:00"
description: "Descrição do plano 1"
id: 1
operationsIds: [1, 2]
}
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that the values inside the array, don't match the corresponding `fabricPlanId` of the product.

Comment: Which array? plan_desc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, the `plan_desc` are in a random order. The cause for this is

```
this.products.forEach( element => { 
      this.fabricplanservice.getfabricplan(element.fabricPlanId).subscribe(
    ...
```

you cannot control how long each request will take, so some will return sooner, some later and whenever they return, they are added to the list --> the order is random.

However it is pretty easy to make a request for each item and then get the list order with rxjs [`forkjoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

```
// create a request for each product (dont fire it yet)
const plans_desc$ = this.products.map( element => 
  this.fabricplanservice.getfabricplan(element.fabricPlanId).pipe(
    // map it to the value you want
    map((response) => {
      this.fabricplan = response;
      return this.fabricplan['description'];
    }),
    // replace 404 responses with the  'No fabric plan'
    // if not 404 throw the error again
    catchError((error) => {
      if(error.status === 404){
        return 'No fabric plan';
      } else {
        throwError(error);
      }
    }));
  });

// now make the actuall requests. Forkjoin will return, when all requests are completed.
// the order will be the be how the requests where added, not when the completed
forkJoin(plans_desc$).subscribe((plans_desc) => this.plan_desc = plans_desc);
```

(I wrote his code here)

imports:

```
import {forkJoin, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {map, catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: I added the `import { forkJoin  } from 'rxjs';` but still appear some errors for exemple, can't find name map, catcherror and thorwerror. What's the import that is missing?

Comment: I already found them in the link you posted, thanks, just one more thing the `plans_desc$` in the forkjoin appears the following error ` Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObservableInput<unknown>'.`

Comment: ahhh yes, it's not `foreach`, its the standard JS map, because you are mapping your porducts to another array